# Let $f$ be a real valued function on the interval $(0,1)$. Prove that the set of points of discontinuity of the _first kind_ is at most countable.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a real valued function on the interval $(0,1)$. Prove that the set of points of discontinuity of the *first kind* is at most countable.

*Definition* $x_0$ is a point of discontinuity of the *first kind* of $f$ if $$\lim_{x \to x_0^+} f(x) > \lim_{x \to x_0^-} f(x) $$ and both of the above limits exist.

There is a straight forward way to show this fact for a monotone function (using the following Hint), but I do not know how to proceed for the general case.

*Hint* For each $n\in \mathbb{N}$ show that the set of points $x$ for which $$|\lim_{t \to x^+} f(t) - \lim_{t \to x^-} f(t)| > \frac{1}{n}  $$ is at most countable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call $x_0$ a $\frac1n$-discontinuity of the first kind if
$$|\lim_{x \to x_0^+} f(x) - \lim_{x \to x_0^-} f(x)| > \frac{1}{n}  $$
Since the left and right limits exist, there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $|f(y)-\lim_{x \to x_0^-} f(x)| < \frac1{2n}$ if $y \in (x_0-\epsilon,x_0)$, and $|f(y)-\lim_{x \to x_0^+} f(x)| < \frac1{2n}$ if $y \in (x_0,x_0+\epsilon)$.  Therefore any $y \in (x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon)$ with $y \ne x_0$ cannot be a $\frac1n$-discontinuity of the first kind.

Go from there.

Comment: How can you assume there is such $y$ ? Are you assuming piecewise continuity ?

Comment: I am just quoting the definition of left and right limit.